# What does .php question mark = mean?

Tags: php

I know this is a dumb question, but I can't figure out what this means. When I see .php?=. Also wondering how will go about using that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Read up on $_GET variables: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Related, but not a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: @DavidThomas is it really related? i think that article is about comparison...

Comment: @DavidThomas not related...

Comment: Simply `.php?=` means nothing. It could make sense only if in php code there is a strange "handmade" check of url and get

Comment: It's related only in the sense that this is a beginner question, and I'd anticipate future questions asking 'what is `&&`?' And so forth; hence my 'not a dupe' (attempt at) classification.

Comment: @David Thomas Future questions like what's && won't be coming for me as I already know what that is. I try to find answer for this question with out asking, but was not able to find the answer.

Comment: No problem, 'beginner' questions are still welcome, and we're not averse to teaching those newer than ourselves; it is difficult to search for syntax, since the literal characters are often used for specific purposes in searches and database queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It marks the start of a query string,which can be accessed with GET.

```
http://somesite.com/index.php?foo=1

$_GET['foo'] will be 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The question mark is supposed to mark the start of the portion of a GET request where you can pass it variables (known as the query string).
This is not just for PHP.

Example :

if you send the following :

> http://www.myserver.com/file.php?something=12&another=blah

to a php file that looks like this :

```
<?php 

print($_GET["something"]);
print($_GET["another"]);

?>
```

the result will be this :

```
12blah
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not

`.php?=`

There must be a variable name before `=`.

Like this:

`.php?x=`.

This is variable passed from URL to script. You can read this variable from PHP code like this:

`$_GET['x']`

More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

suppose I have file1.php open and in it, I want to create a statement, which passes values to another page, file2.php. This is usually done through an html link or button. I will do it through a link in the below example.

In file1.php, I will include some code that does that:

```
<a href="edit.php?attribute=value> Link name</a>
```

This creates a "Link name" hyperlink that, when clicked, passes values by "GET" function into "edit.php".

I will catch the same in file2.php using the following statement in file2.php:

```
$variable=$_GET['attribute']
```

P.S. If you didn't understand anything, try forgetting every worry you have and now read the answer again.